# Resolve dependency conflict with dash-bootstrap-components, dash, and django-plotly-dash 1.6.6

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, plotly-dash

I am trying to build a docker image for a django web app that has dash and plotly components.
However, my build fails  with the following error

```
The conflict is caused by:
#11 39.72     dash-bootstrap-components 1.0.2 depends on dash>=2.0.0
#11 39.72     django-plotly-dash 1.6.6 depends on dash<1.21.0 and >=1.11
#11 39.72
#11 39.72 To fix this you could try to:
#11 39.72 1. loosen the range of package versions you've specified
#11 39.72 2. remove package versions to allow pip attempt to solve the dependency conflict
```

I've tried loosening the ranges and removing package versions but am still getting the same error. After some research it appears django-plotly-dash is not updated for dash>2.0
Is there a work around? My webpage works fine locally so I'm not sure why building it is now having the issue.

Comment: yes probably for now you will have to downgrade your dash packages.
dash                           1.21.0
dash-bootstrap-components      0.13.0
dash-core-components           1.17.1
dash-daq                       0.5.0
dash-html-components           1.1.4
dash-renderer                  1.9.1
dash-table                     4.12.0
django-plotly-dash             1.6.4
I hope this helps you

Comment: Thanks! Yes that helped!